# Storing unsigned integer in a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, unsigned-integer

I'm constructing an octree data structure, and to save memory for the final nodes I would like the store the values directly in the pointer instead of having to create an object that's made to hold 8 children.

My data type is a uint32_t which means that a pointer have enough bits to hold it on either x86 or amd64.

So how do I store an unsigned 32bit integer in a x86 or amd64 pointer?

pseudo code:

```
uint32_t i = 123;
Octree* ptr = i;
uint32_t ii = ptr;
std::cout << ii << std::endl; //Prints 123
```

How is this possible?

Comment: uint32_t i = 123;
Octree* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Octree*>(i);
uint32_t ii = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(ptr);

Comment: @FamZ: although on x86 that should work, it's technically illegal and *there are* some bizarre platforms where that would result in a crash (even just *referring* to invalid pointers triggers hardware exceptions on these CPUs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing an unsigned integer straight *in* a pointer portably isn't allowed, but you can:

- do the reverse: you can store your pointer in an unsigned integer; specifically, `uintptr_t` is explicitly guaranteed by the standard to be big enough to let pointers survive the roundtrip;
- use a `union`:

  ```
  union NodePtr {
      Octree *child;
      uint32_t value;
  }
  ```

  here `child` and `value` share the same memory location, and you are allowed to read only from the one where you last wrote; when you are in a terminal node you use `value`, otherwise use `child`.

Comment: Is there any overhead of using union? Would the union above take the same space as a raw pointer?

Comment: @KaareZ: `union`s are virtually free on any decent implementation - they are just there to tell the compiler that you are going to access that memory with multiple types, so the most stringent alignment requirement applies; the size of the union is "sufficient to store the largest of its data members" (and, in practice, it's normally as large as its largest member).

Comment: Okay, then that is a very great solution sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can store int as a pointer with casts:

```
uint32_t i = 123;
Octree* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Octree*>(i);
uint32_t ii = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(ptr);
std::cout << ii << std::endl; //Prints 123
```

But if you do it this way I can't see how you detect that a given Octree* actually stores data and is not a pointer to another Octree

Comment: I would have a bool flag for that.

Comment: As said above, although this will work on x86 and other common architectures, technically it isn't portable (pointers are allowed to have trap representations).